# How do I display unicode characters in the Eclipse console window?

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode

I am creating a small Java application that uses Unicode characters to create rows and columns of boxes in the console window in Eclipse Keplar. My code works completely fine but the output of each Unicode character I print is a small box instead of the Unicode character I want to print.

My code is as follows. I have two classes.

My main class:

```
package assign03;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assign03 {

private static int columns;
private static int cWidth;
private static int rows;
private static int rHeight;
private static Table table;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        table = new Table();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number of columns: ");
        columns = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the width of the columns: ");
        cWidth = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: ");
        rows = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the width of the rows: ");
        rHeight = input.nextInt();

        table.printFirstLine(columns, cWidth);

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int rh = 0; rh < rHeight; rh++) {
                table.printVerticalLine(columns, cWidth);
            }
            if (r < (rows - 1)
                table.printInternalLine(columns, cWidth);
        }

        table.printLastLine(columns, cWidth);
        input.close();
    }
}
```

And my Table.java class:

```
package assign03;

public class Table {

    private char firstLine[] = { '\u2501', '\u250F', '\u2533', '\u2513' };
    private char internalLine[] = { '\u2501', '\u2523', '\u254B', '\u252B' };
    private char lastLine[] = { '\u2501', '\u2517', '\u253B', '\u251B' };
    private char verticalLine[] = { '\u2503' };
    private char whiteSpace[] = { '\u2003' };

    public void printFirstLine(int columns, int cWidth) {

        System.out.print(firstLine[1]);

        for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
            for (int cw = 0; cw < cWidth; cw++) {
                System.out.print(firstLine[0]);
            }
            if (c < (columns - 1))
                System.out.print(firstLine[2]);
        }

        System.out.println(firstLine[3]);
    }

    public void printVerticalLine(int columns, int cWidth) {
        for (int c = 0; c <= columns; c++) {
            System.out.print(verticalLine[0]);
            for (int cw = 0; cw < cWidth; cw++) {
                System.out.print(whiteSpace[0]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void printInternalLine(int columns, int cWidth) {
        System.out.print(internalLine[1]);

        for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
            for (int w = 0; w < cWidth; w++) {
                System.out.print(internalLine[0]);
            }
            if (c < (columns - 1))
                System.out.print(internalLine[2]);
        }

        System.out.println(internalLine[3]);
    }

    public void printLastLine(int columns, int cWidth) {

        System.out.print(lastLine[1]);

        for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
            for (int w = 0; w < cWidth; w++) {
                System.out.print(lastLine[0]);
            }
            if (c < (columns - 1))
                System.out.print(lastLine[2]);
        }

        System.out.println(lastLine[3]);
    }
}
```

When the application runs, the output is as follows. I use inputs of 4 for columns, rows, column width, and row width.

[image: Console Output]

Any reason why my console output looks like that? Can anybody help me get the Unicode to display properly? Thanks.

Comment: Can Eclipse's console output font be customized? If yes, have you tried selecting a different font?

Comment: Check this out http://paranoid-engineering.blogspot.com/2008/05/getting-unicode-output-in-eclipse.html

Comment: I've already changed the console font and added -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to eclipse.ini and I still get the same output.

Answer (score 11):

What worked for me was to go to Preferences, under Workspace, and change "Text file encoding" to UTF-8.

Comment: This works too. You can find the exact setting under (Eclipse 2018-12): `Window - Preferences - General - Workspace - Text file encoding` (bottom left of the window).

Comment: And use the search option if you cant find the `Workspace` section.

Comment: I just came across this post again: So far writing e.g. .xml files has been working fine with Eclipse's (2020-06) `UTF-8` setting but yesterday a .txt file was missing a bunch of symbols and even the console didn't print them properly. I tried using `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` with the `OutputStreamWriter` but it only started writing correctly when I switched Eclipse's encoding back to default (yes, still with the charset). It looks like it depends on what the encoding of your source (file) is.

Answer (score 10):

The small box means that the current font doesn't have those symbols.

You will have to find a font which supports them and configure the console font (search the preferences for "console") to use it.

If it still doesn't work, make sure you have configured the Java application that you're running (i.e. which prints to the console) to emit UTF-8. In Eclipse, you can do that by opening the launch config and setting "Console Encoding" to UTF-8 ([see this blog post](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/) or [here](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/02/21/pro-tip-unicode-characters-in-the-eclipse-console/))

Comment: I ended up using different UTF-8 symbols to create my boxes and left the settings the way they were. The font didn't like the characters I was using so I used comparable but different characters, which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

All the solutions I found referred to configuring Eclipse to use UTF-8 including Workspace preferences and text file encoding. I already had all those configuration settings set correctly. Yet I still saw only several lines of question mark characters, i.e. `?`, when I ran the code in the question.

While not changing any of those configuration settings, what worked for me was explicitly setting the [System] property `stdout.encoding`.
(Note that I am using Eclipse 2023-03 and [Oracle's] JDK 20.)

My [Eclipse] *Run Configuration* window:

[image: Eclipse run configuration]

Here is output appearing in Eclipse console (as text) when I run the (unaltered) code in the question:

```
Enter the number of columns: 4
Enter the width of the columns: 4
Enter the number of rows: 4
Enter the width of the rows: 4
┏━━━━┳━━━━┳━━━━┳━━━━┓
┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    
┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    
┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    
┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    
┣━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━┫
┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    
┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    
┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    
┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    
┣━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━┫
┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    
┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    
┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    
┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    
┣━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━┫
┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    
┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    
┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    
┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    
┗━━━━┻━━━━┻━━━━┻━━━━┛
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Using a similar JDK as yours, I wonder if this is specific to that JDK, or is it a deeper problem?