# some nonASCII Characters are coming like a thick vertical line in talend 5.6

Tags: talend

I have a file with name "→Ψjohn.txt" and now i want to remove those special characters from the file name and update the file name as "john.txt". But talend is recognizing those characters as thick vertical line so it is not recognizing the source file in the physical location.can anyone please suggest a solution.

I have this file in database as well as physical location and when I am reading the file from the database it has to remove the special characters and update the same in the database as well as physical location.

in database the file looks like this
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mq8v.png)

when I am reading from database using talend it looks like following
[talend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20IfN.png)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show what you have created so far and what output you are getting (thick lines?)

Comment: In databse it looks like this :http://i.stack.imgur.com/1mq8v.png

When I am reading from database using talend it looks like following:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/20IfN.png

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to specify the exact file name, you can use `tFilelist` and get all file in a specific directory, you can also regex to mask some names, for example iterate over all `*john.txt`. 
Once you get the actual filename, use a regex to remove unwanted characters for example : `\W` for non word characters and rename the file through a system command or using `tFileCopy`.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the pictures this is not a Talend issue but has to do with the font used in the Talend (Eclipse) console and the enconding setting of Java.

Those rectangles (better visible with a bigger font size) show that the font cannot represent your characters - it has no symbols for it.

**Talend (Eclipse) settings**

In Talend, navigate to `Window / Preferences` and choose `General / Appearance / Colors and Fonts` (as described in the [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-consoleAppearance.htm)). Check what font you are using for `Debug / Console font`. I've had good results with the font `Consolas`, which is set from Talend version 6 onwards. Beforehand it was `Courier New`.

**Java encoding**

You should check that Java uses UTF-8 encoding to display the characters. The `Console Enconding` has to be set to UTF-8. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20053054/5191221) for an explanation how to do this.

**Alternative**

Alternatively you could store all the log data into a file and open this file in e.g. Notepad++ to see if the output is generated correctly and only displayed wrong.