# How to print unique ASCII in Eclipse's console?

Tags: java, character, ascii

How can I print ASCII characters that are not added in the Eclipse Console? I need to use some charachters to my game and every time I get "?" or smething like that? For example I woudl like to use 11034 in decimal or \u2B1B from source code for java. Thanks for help!

Comment: You can check answers under this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050309/how-do-i-display-unicode-characters-in-the-eclipse-console-window)

Comment: Terminology check: The [ASCII character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set) is limited. It sounds like you are asking about non-ASCII characters, such as this one: [Unicode Character 'BLACK LARGE SQUARE'](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2b1b/index.htm).

Comment: From the Java programming point of view, you simply print it: `System.out.println(" \u2B1B")` for example.   Beyond that, it's a matter of your specific display, and in particular, having a font with that character.  I tried it at one of the online Java IDEs, and got the expected black square.

Comment: `System.out.println("\u2B1B")` works fine on my Eclipse console. You may be using a font that doesn't contain that character.

Answer (score 0):

ASCII is a seven bit code that contains 128 characters. Intentionally it is the same as the first 128 characters found in UNICODE using UTF-8. The code point \u2B1B is way beyond that and therefore no ASCII.

If that code cannot be printed, it is likely the font you are using does not contain a [glyph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph#Typography) for it.

Learn about Unicode characters and glyphs. A good starting point is https://home.unicode.org/

Comment: I agree with all of this - but it reads more like general guidance and advice, and not an actual answer to the specific (admittedly implied) question: _How to print specific non-ASCII characters in the Eclipse console?_