# Java Default Encoding

Tags: java, windows, encoding, javac

Is it still necessary on Windows to add the `-encoding UTF-8` parameter to the Java Compiler, when using German *Umlaut ß* in sources?
I thought that UTF-8 is the default for Java, isn't it?

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Viel Spaß beim üben!");
  }
}
```

Open Windows-CMD:

```
C:\temp>javac Main.java && java Main
Viel SpaÃ? beim Ã¼ben!

C:\temp>javac -encoding UTF-8 Main.java && java Main
Viel Spaß beim üben!
```

[image]

Comment: Which Java version are you using? UTF-8 is only the default in Java 18 or higher (see [JEP 400: UTF-8 by Default](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400)), in earlier Java versions it follows the settings of the OS (which on Windows generally results in a single-byte character set like windows-1252).

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank You. I was using the wrong JDK here. Thoght it is 20 but was 17. 
Problem solved.
Thanks for the Link again to JEP 400

Comment: The problem isn't the encoding of the file, it's the encoding of your terminal. Windows terminal doesn't default to UTF-8

Comment: Notepad++ is telling you that the file _Main.java_ is UTF-8. This has nothing to do with the encoding of the string passed to `System.out.println` when you run the code. I don't know in which Java version it was added, but there is [`System`] property _stdout.encoding_. Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050309/how-do-i-display-unicode-characters-in-the-eclipse-console-window/76020744#76020744

Comment: @Abra Support for _stdout.encoding_ was added in JDK 19. It is formally documented in the Java 19 javadoc  for `System.getProperties()`, but is not there in the corresponding Java 18 javadoc. Also see [_"New system properties for System.out and System.err (JDK-8283620)"_](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/19-relnote-issues.html) in the JDK 19 Release Notes.

Answer (score 2):

Per the Comments…

- In Java 18+, the default character encoding for most purposes is UTF-8. See [*JEP 400: UTF-8 by Default*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400) for details.
- In Java 17 and earlier, for most purposes the default character encoding is specific to the host OS platform.

Tip: It never hurts to explicitly specify your intended character encoding by passing optional arguments, rather than rely implicitly on defaults.

---

The results of your code:

```
System.out.println("Viel Spaß beim üben!");
```

… is *not* controlled by Java. Java does not create, own, or control your particular console. Your console has its own character encoding. Either you need to output text from Java to match that encoding, or you must change the encoding used by your console to be UTF-8 (recommended).

---

Your screenshot of Notepad++ app is irrelevant. The text-editor is communicating its guess as to the characters encoding of the Java source code file. That encoding has nothing to do with the encoding of your `String` object `"Viel Spaß beim üben!"`. And it has nothing to do with your console’s character encoding.

By the way, unless you have embedded a [BOM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) within your file, a text-editor can only *guess* at the character encoding of a file, but not *know* with certainty.

---

So, to review, we have  multiple different places with a character encoding at play in your Question:

- Character encoding of *.java* source code files.
- Character encoding of `System.out`.
- Character encoding of your console app that displays the text sent by `System.out`.

Those last two must match, `System.out` and the console. A mismatch there is a common problem, as you may notice when searching Stack Overflow. Some terminal/console apps do not default to UTF-8, unfortunately.

To verify the character encoding of the console associated with your JVM, call [`System.console`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#console()) to get a [`Console`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Console.html) object.

```
CharSet charSet = System.console().charset() ;  // Java 17+.
```